# How to Show Ansible Host Vars and Inventory Vars

Tags: ansible

Is there a command in Ansible in which I can see all the variables for a host. such as variables from the inventory and also from the host and group vars.

Ive tried `ansible-inventory` but that just provided inventory vars. The other options all seem to be printing via a playbook.

EDIT:

Ive tried the following.

```
ansible -m debug -i ../inventory.yaml -a "var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]" "spine1-nxos"
```

But this only works when Im within the folder of my host vars therefore ... the final questions are: how do I get the group vars and how do I provide it to the folder with the host and group vars.

Comment: Cross site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208819/list-all-ansible-variables-for-a-host-or-group-with-an-ad-hoc-command

Comment: I saw the post previous. The marked answer doesn't actually work. As the post is 8 years old I suspect this is due to updates to Ansible, as for why it no longer works.

Comment: It does work, but for some reason, the answerer left the name of the host/group targeted out of the proposed command.

Comment: Example of what works for me: `ansible -m debug -a "var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]" node1` (`node1` being one of my inventory node)

Comment: Ah ok I see. But if I run: ansible -m debug -i inventory.yaml -a "var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]" "spine1-nxos" then this doesnt take into account my host vars. Which I suspect is due to them being in the playbook folder.

Comment: Could you do a `tree` on the playbook folder and point, in an [edit] of the question where they are in the file hierarchy?

Comment: Made a edit. Not sure if the tree will really help. Can add if need be. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: host vars can be in your inventory and/or in a folder adjacent to where you launch `ansible(-playbook)`. For the first, they will be read depending on the inventory you use (i.e. a `host_vars` folder should exist in `..` from your example command since you use `../inventory.yml`). For the second, a `host_vars` folder should exist in `.`. You can replace `host_vars` with `group_vars` in my previous explanation. For more on loading order, see [variable precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)